# Checking unique enteries in pandas dataframe of user id interactions

Tags: pandas, dataframe, unique

I have this dataframe which looks like this:

user_id : Represents user

question_id : Represent question number

user_answer : which option user has opted for the specific question from (A,B,C,D)

correct_answer: What is correct answer for that specific question

correct : if 0.0 it means users answer was not right , if 1.0 it means user answer is right

elapsed_time : it represents time in minutes user took to answer that question

| user_id | question_id | user_answer | correct_answer | correct | elapsed_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 130 | A | B | 0.0 | 2.00 |
| 1 | 130 | B | B | 1.0 | 5.00 |
| 1 | 130 | B | B | 1.0 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 10 | C | D | 0.0 | 7.00 |
| 2 | 10 | A | D | 0.0 | 9.00 |
| 2 | 10 | B | D | 0.0 | 13.00 |
| 2 | 10 | D | D | 1.0 | 4.00 |
| 2 | 10 | D | D | 1.0 | 1.50 |

**What I want another dataframe to look like is this**

| user_id | Questions Attempted | Unique Questions Attempted | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9000 | 6000 | =(6000/13169)*100 |
| 2 | 5000 | 4800 | =(5000/13169)*100 |
| 5 | 12000 | 10000 | =(10000/13169)*100 |
| 15 | 1000 | 30 | =(30/13169)*100 |
| 23 | 255 | 255 | =(255/13169)*100 |

**WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR IS THIS**

```
df_total_questions_attempted = df.groupby(['user_iD'], as_index=False , sort=False)['question_id'].count()

df_total_questions_attempted = df_total_questions_attempted.rename(columns={'question_id': 'Total Questions Attempted'})
```

This gives me the **Questions Attempted** column , How do i find the **Unique Questions Attempted** column?

and for **Unique Questions Attempted** column , I need that unique entry when the user has corrected the answer.

**For example :**

| user_id | question_id | user_answer | correct_answer | correct | elapsed_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 130 | A | B | 0.0 | 2.00 |
| 1 | 130 | B | B | 1.0 | 5.00 |
| 1 | 130 | B | B | 1.0 | 2.00 |
| 2 | 10 | C | D | 0.0 | 7.00 |
| 2 | 10 | A | D | 0.0 | 9.00 |
| 2 | 10 | D | D | 1.0 | 4.00 |
| 2 | 10 | D | D | 1.0 | 1.50 |

In this dataframe : the unique question attempt should consider when the user has corrected the question for the very first time ,  as in this case
**user 1** has corrected the question in 2nd and 3rd attempt. it should consider the **2nd attempt**.
same goes for user 2 as well , user 2 has corrected the question in 3rd and 4th attempt , it should consider the **3rd attempt**

Comment: How is count `Percentage` column?

Comment: @jezrael : the number of total unique questions are : 13169.
Thus the formula to be used for percentage would be :  (# of Unique questions attempted / 13169) *100

Comment: Super, just EDIT answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper column for first correct answer per `user_id` and `question_id` by chain mask for test `==` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df['new'] = df['correct'].eq(1) & ~df.duplicated(['user_id','question_id','correct'])
print (df)
   user_id  question_id user_answer correct_answer  correct  elapsed_time  \
0        1          130           A              B      0.0           2.0   
1        1          130           B              B      1.0           5.0   
2        1          130           B              B      1.0           2.0   
3        2           10           C              D      0.0           7.0   
4        2           10           A              D      0.0           9.0   
5        2           10           B              D      0.0          13.0   
6        2           10           D              D      1.0           4.0   
7        2           10           D              D      1.0           1.5   

     new  
0  False  
1   True  
2  False  
3  False  
4  False  
5  False  
6   True  
7  False
```

And then for count `True`s aggregate `sum` and for count unique `questions` use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['user_id'])
        .agg(**{'Questions Attempted':('question_id','nunique'),
                'Unique Questions Attempted':('new','sum')})
        .reset_index())
```

Last seems for percentage is necessary divide by number of unique questions:

```
no_uniq_q = df['correct'].nunique()
df1['Percentage'] = df1['Unique Questions Attempted'].div(no_uniq_q).mul(100)
print (df1)
   user_id  Questions Attempted  Unique Questions Attempted  Percentage
0        1                    1                           1        50.0
1        2                    1                           1        50.0
```